Android app for improving gender recognition
I used to use an Android app called "King of German Grammar", silly name but it was useful for improving my knowledge of the gender of German nouns. It would display a noun and you had to decide the gender of that noun, and it had a great scoring system. Simple, but it really helped me when I was starting to learn German. Unfortunately it is no longer available.
I passed my B2 several years ago and have attended C1 conversation courses at local VHS colleges. My major problem with German is still the indentification of the gender of nouns and so I was wondering if anyone knew of a similar app with a large vocabulary to "King of German Grammar" that I could use whenever I get a few minutes waiting in line, etc. I wouldn't mind paying for a suitable app.

This is not a question about German grammar, German vocabulary or other aspects of German language and therefore does not fit to german.stackexchange. It fits better to https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com which explicitly deals with methods and tools (including apps) for learning languages. It might also fit well to https://android.stackexchange.com which is dedicated to all kinds of android apps.

The generic resources question for German is here, but even the software section does not seem to provide something appropriate.

In contrast to all those "please decipher this old handwritten letter" posts, this one could be useful for further visitors.

I've googled for apk archive german grammar king and found that a page with the name "APKPure" is still providing a download of that app. You could try to download and install the APK but it might harm your Android phone as it is no official download. If you are technical enough you could try to reverse engineer the app from the given APK. Or you could try to use an Android emulator on your computer for starting the app.
